# Photoshop: How can I change the layer type?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I was given a .PSD file from my designer and I'm trying to change a layer from "Curve" to "Hue/Saturation"

[image]

However, if I highlight the curve thumbnail (shown by the pink arrow) and press delete it deletes the whole thing.

I also tried creating a new layer of the existing layer using the "Adjustments" tab, but it creates a new layer that is different (notice it's just a quite square, not one with words like the original one:

[image]

How would I create an identical layer of the "Cheers to 50 years" and then adjust the hue / saturation?

Answer (score 3):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click the layer mask before you delete the curves layer, it will load the mask as a selection.

Now, you can add a new Hue/Saturation adjustment layer, and the layer mask will be replicated with that adjustment layer, then you can delete the old curves adjustment layer.

Finally if you <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click between the two layers, it will clip the adjustment to only the layer below.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a new Hue/Saturation adjustment layer.
2. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the layer mask from your Curves adjustment layer to the new Hue/Saturation layer.
3. Confirm the "Replace Layer Mask" dialog that pops up.
4. Delete the Curves adjustment layer

[image: animated gif of the process]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to keep the selection of the text from the mask below?

If so, just right click your Hue/Sat layer & select "Create Clipping Mask"

You'll see it will adopt another of those 'left & down' arrows & will then conform to the mask of the layer underneath [even though it won't actually show the mask in the icon]

A rough attempt…

[image]